# PHP Array to PHP variables

Tags: php

I got a PHP multidimensional array, I want to create variables from it first element as variable name and the second element as the variable value. I want to use this logic to print create the variables based on the language selected, the first column always will have the same names but the second value will generate different strings based on the language selected.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => el1
            [1] => Grouping
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => el2
            [1] => Type
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => el3
            [1] => Starting Date
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => el4
            [1] => Ending Date
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => el5
            [1] => Section
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => el6
            [1] => Cell
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => el7
            [1] => Client
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => el8
            [1] => Status
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => el9
            [1] => Article
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => el10
            [1] => Search
        )

)
```

I want to assign the `[0]` value as a variable name and `[1]` as the variable value, the declaration should be in this way related to my array presented before:

```
<?php
    el1="Grouping";
    el2="Type";
    el3="Starting Date";
?>
```

... and so on.

I want to echo out on the HTML page the string from the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
foreach ($array as $index => $subarray) {
    ${$subarray[0]} = $subarray[1];
}
```

1. You loop throught your big array
2. You get the first value with key 0 and transform it as variable : see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.variables.variable.php)
3. You assign the value with key 1 and assign it to your variable

Test :

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "test",
        1 => "value"
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "test2",
        1 => "value2"
    )
);

foreach ($array as $index => $subarray) {
    ${$subarray[0]} = $subarray[1];
}

var_dump($test, $test2);
```

The output is :

```
string 'value' (length=5)
string 'value2' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop through the array should do the trick:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
 $temp = $item[0];
 ${$temp} = $item[1];
}
```